# Wave equation: $y=A \sin(\omega t-kx)$ or $y=A\sin(kx-\omega t)$?

Tags: classical-mechanics, waves

What is correct wave equation:
$y=A \sin(\omega t-kx)$ or $y=A\sin(kx-\omega t)$?

How are these wave equations used in the positive $x$-direction
and negative $x$-direction?

Comment: Both travel along positive x axis as t increases. See https://www.desmos.com/calculator/4bujob8guo. Draw the initial graph of $\sin(x)$ and then say the graph of $\sin(x-0.1)$. You will realize that it moves towards positive x axis.

Comment: $\sin(wt -kx)  = -\sin(kx-wt)$. They are the same apart from a phase shift.

Answer (score 6):

One of the problems of illustrating a wave is that the displacement of the particle $y$ is a function of two variables the equilibrium position of the particle $x$ relative to some origin and time $t$.
So to graph a wave one might draw.

[image: ![enter image description here]

However is is more practical to compare the displacement with time of particles at fixed positions or the displacement with position of particles at fixed times.

[image]

The graph above shows the motion of a particle as a function of time at a fixed position, $x=0$ in this case.

If one now adds the graph of displacement against time for a particle at $x = \Delta x$, ie at an equilibrium position  further away from the origin in the positive direction.

[image]

What one notes from these two graphs is that the red graph lags behind the grey graph.
This means that the wave is travelling in the positive x-direction.
You can think of it as the particle at $x=0$ telling the particle at $x = \Delta x$ what to do but that information is delayed because the information (wave) travels at a finite speed.

With $\omega t$ and $kx$ reversed you will see that it is still a wave travelling in the positive x-direction but $\pi$ out of phase with the other one.

[image]

If you look at my attempted representation of the 3D graph you are essentially looking at a series of sections of the graph which are parallel to the $y-t$ plane ie looking left from the right hand side.

---

The other wave of representing a wave is to draw a wave profile which is essentially an instantaneous photograph of the wave.

[image]

[image]

Both the graphs illustrate quite clearly that the waves are travelling in the positive x-direction.

If you look at my attempted representation of the 3D graph you are essentially looking at a series of sections of the graph which are parallel to the $y-x$ plane ie looking from the front into the screen.

Comment: Sir, in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/308212/explanation-of-the-wave-equation-yx-t-ft-x-v/308220#comment1411451_308220) linked post, it is said that wave equation is of the form $y(x,t)=f\left(t-\frac{x}{v}\right)$, is the reason for considering only trigonometric functions that they are periodic? If that is the case, then what would $y(x,t)=e^{t-\frac{x}{v}}$ mean? or any other function... would it also represent a wave?

Comment: The equation that you quote is a solution of the wave equation as is $y(x,t) = \frac{1}{t-\frac x v}$.

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct equations for a wave traveling in the $+x$ direction. This can be easily seen from the fact that increasing $t$ requires a corresponding increase in $x$ to keep phase constant. The two expressions only differ by a phase of $\pi$ because $\sin (kx-\omega t) = \sin (\omega t - kx + \pi)$

The expression for the wave in the $-x$ direction is $\sin (kx+\omega t)$