# For a sine (or cosine) wave, how can the $kx$ be different from $\omega t$?

Tags: waves, frequency, wavelength

I'm trying to learn wave mechanics and came across the equation that states wave as a function of $x$ and $t$ and specifically $(kx - \omega t)$. In my faulty imagination, the $kx$ is always equal to $\omega t$, as both seem to be a measure of angular "distance" from a reference point of zero (start).

So my question is, why can't the quantity $(kx - \omega t)$ be always equal to zero?

Comment: Because $x$ and $t$ are two independant variables?

Comment: But for a uniform linear velocity, which is natural for a wave, x and t are no longer independent, right?

Comment: they are still independent.  There is nothing preventing you from selecting $x$ and $t$ at your heart's desire.  Once you have fixed a pair of (x,t), you have located a point on the wave, and this point will "travel" towards the right (assuming $k>0$ so as to keep $kx-\omega t$ constant, but you can select any pair $(x,t)$ with $x$ and $t$ chosen completely independently.

Comment: I still don't understand. I thought value of x is automatically determined when we fix the value of t, because the wave is moving along x with a fixed velocity? Am I missing something?

Comment: $x(t)= v_0t + x_0$ where $x_0$ is the initial position, which you are free to choose independently of $t$.

Comment: My answer to this question might help you understand? http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304780/wave-equation-y-a-sin-omega-t-kx-or-y-a-sinkx-omega-t/304820#304820

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this animation:
[image: Sine Wave]

Along the x axis is our x and the sine wave is moving with time. If you were to stop the animation and change x you're looking at x with a constant t and we can see this covers all values of the sine wave. If we were instead to only look at one value of x and plot out all the positions the wave has through time, this would also cover all values of the sine wave.

The x and t are independent of each other but to get a value from the sine wave we have to know where and when we're looking.

Comment: Thanks for the nice animation. I realized this just before you have posted this. But this is is the answer I was looking for!