# Explanation of the time quantities in the travelling wave equation

Tags: waves, time

I know that $y=A\sin(\omega t-kx)$, but this can also be written as $y=A\sin \omega (t-x/v)$. What I don't understand is what the quantity $(t-x/v)$ represents. Both quantities have the units of time, but which time in space each quantity represents is what is confusing me.

Comment: Related https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304780/104696

Comment: Related : [Significance of wave number?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/265008/significance-of-wave-number/265022#265022).

Comment: note that f(y-z) translates (shifts) f(y) to the right by the amount z.

Answer (score 0):

The quantity $(t-x/v)$ does appear in electromagnetic and quantum field theory (and elsewhere), bearing the name 'retarded time', where $v$ is the speed of light. However, I would say that $A\sin(\omega t-kx)$ is the 'most meaningful' form of the wave, and without specific context, that quantity is very uninterpretable.

Comment: Thank you. In my textbook x represtents the distance travelled by the wave and v is the veocity of the wave. What my book does not specify is which time, t stands for. I figured that if i knew the time in space, t stands for i would be able to understand how the overall equation works.