# How to decide equation of a wave?

Tags: waves

I was a bit confused about equation of waves. I encountered 2 wave equations: 
$$y(x,t)=a\sin(\omega t-kx)$$$$y(x,t)=a\sin(kx-\omega t) $$

What is the difference between them? Can anyone please explain me using their graphs?

Comment: The formulae you wrote are not equations of waves. Ther are two particular waves (one out of phase by $\pi$ with respect to the other). A wave equation is in general a partial differential equation whose solutions may have the form of your functions.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/304780/104696)

Comment: @GiorgioP OP said "equation of waves" not "wave equation". His equations are equations of waves.

Comment: @user45664  which is a common way of naming things, but a funny way, since there is no equation et all!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to the [graphs.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/kw0itwg4j5)

As you can clearly see, by changing time that both waves are moving towards +x axis and
are $\pi$ rad out of phase.

This can be explained easily because of the fact that $\sin(-x) = -\sin(x)$ so they would have $y$ of oppsite signs at any given time.