# General equation of a traveling wave

Tags: waves, conventions

I have seen the equation of a wave written as  $y = A \sin (kx – \omega t)$. However sometimes I see it written as $y=A\sin(\omega t-kx).$ Please notify the correct one and provide sufficient reasons.

Comment: Please do your research on this website because this question has been asked a lot on this website. Here's the [closed](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/451328/how-to-decide-equation-of-a-wave/451336#451336) question here is the [first](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/304780/wave-equation-y-a-sin-omega-t-kx-or-y-a-sinkx-omega-t) one

Comment: This is not a wave equation  and the two forms only differ by a minus sign or 180 degrees phase.

Answer (score 3):

They are both "correct" if you just want to describe a sinusoidal wave, they are just off by a phase difference. Some useful identities:

$$\sin(-\theta)=-\sin(\theta)$$
$$\sin(\theta+\pi)=-\sin(\theta)$$

Therefore
$$\sin(-\theta)=\sin(\theta+\pi)$$
i.e. negating the argument just adds a phase difference. Both equations still describe a right traveling wave of speed $\omega/k$ and amplitude $A$. More generally you could just include a phase factor to cover all cases:
$$y(x,t)=A\sin(kx-\omega t +\phi)$$

The only reason you would choose one over another is if you are given certain initial conditions. For example if $y(\pi/2k,0)=A$ (as well as first partial derivatives being equal to $0$) , then you would just have $A\sin(kx-\omega t)$. But both forms you give as well as the general one I have supplied all correctly describe sinusoidal traveling waves.